# C# framework or library with UI to work with databases

Tags: database, c#, user-interface

I am new to databases and I'm searching for some tools (frameworks or libraries) to simplify work with database (sqlite) and focus on learning SQL. I mean UI, Forms, Controls and so on. It is just a waste of time, when I need to create each form manually, to just add, edit or delete a record. I will be really glad for any answer. Or maybe I just do something wrong with standard forms, and I will be also glad to get some tutorials, which describe how to work with databases (sqlite) easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of articles on SQLite [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tags/SQLite). Since you are new to databases I also recommend [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/sql-database-fundamentals-16944?l=w7qq6nAID_6805121157) for general database tutorials. [This](http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/) is a pretty good management tool. There is a beginner's article on using LINQ to SQL [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C).

Comment: +1 because it helps him, even thought that part of his question is off-topic. Do you know of any C# APi or abstraction layer to help him?

Comment: @ Mawg, I added a link to an article on LINQ to SQL for beginners.